# Tornado websocket logging

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I'm trying to implement websockets using Tornado webserver.

My setup looks as follows:

```
from tornado.options import options, define, parse_command_line
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
import logging
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi

from pogows.tornado_sockets import GetSocketHandler, UpdateSocketHandler
from mobile.cleaner import start_cleaning

define('port', type=int, default=8080)
tornado.options.options['log_file_prefix'].set('/var/www/pogo_django/logs/tornado_server.log')
tornado.options.parse_command_line()

<snip>

def main():

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(
        django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
    tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
        [
            ('/hello-tornado', HelloHandler),
            ('/socket/get', GetSocketHandler),
            ('/socket/update', UpdateSocketHandler),
            ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
        ], debug=True)
    logger.info("Tornado POGO server starting...")
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
    server.listen(options.port)
    start_cleaning()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

So far everything looks fine, tornado logs, I see the info message. 
Now, I'm trying to log some stuff from websocket handler classes.

```
class GetSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        print "opening"

    def on_closed(self):
        print "closing"

    def on_message(self, message):
        last_update=datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
        try:
            print "getting_user"
    ...
```

Tornado is governed by [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), with the following configuration:

> [program:pogo_tornado] command=/var/www/pogo_django/tornado_server.py
>   user=www-data stdout_logfile=/var/www/pogo_django/logs/pogo_stdout.log
>   stderr_logfile=/var/www/pogo_django/logs/pogo_stderr.log
>   environment=PYTHONPATH="/var/www/pogo_django/",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="pogo.settings"

I tried a few things.

1. Just use `print` statements, as you see from the above snippet, hoping for supervisord to catch it and send to stdout/stderr logs.
2. Create a separate `logging.getLogger()` instance inside the websocket class and use that.

None of it produces desired results.

When I run tornado from commandline by hand, I do see the `print` version printed to console, but `logging` doesn't work anyway.

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: The reason logging.getLogger() might be failing is that your `supervisord` setup is telling it to log to /var/www/pogo_django/logs/pogo_stdout.log

Comment: I thought so as well, but when I run it outside of `supervisord` I still see nothing in the logs. OTOH, why does the `main()` manage to log properly in both cases, and the handlers don't?

Comment: I would guess that in the handlers they are reusing the logger that tornado setup. You could try making the logger that you create in `main()` global and the reuse that with your handlers.

Comment: Bah, I got it it seems. I was using `getLogger()` without setting logging level and just blindly logging to `DEBUG`. Explicitly using `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` showed me my messages in the logs. Apparently Tornado sets some other level by defaults.. Stupid me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bah, I got it. I was using `getLogger()` without setting logging level and just blindly logging to `DEBUG`.

Explicitly using `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` showed me my messages in the logs.

Apparently Tornado sets some other level by defaults.. Stupid me.